# Unable to build a neural network for regression in Rstudio due to error in match

Tags: r, neural-network, regression

I am a student trying to build a neural network for regression for the first time to predict my variable Math_G3. However I am unable to do it due to the following error:

> Error in x - y : non-conformable arrays
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In cbind(1, act.temp) :
>     number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
>   2: In cbind(1, act.temp) :
>     number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
>
> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
>     'match' requires vector arguments

Here is my code for it:

```
index_train_math<-sample(1:nrow(dat_math),0.6*nrow(dat_math))
#from 1st row to end , put random 70 % AS TRAINING DATA
train_math <- dat_math[index_train_math,]
# training data of math    
maxs <-apply(dat_math,2,max)
mins <- apply(dat_math,2,min)
scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(dat_math,center = mins,scale=maxs-mins))
#returns a matrix that needs to be coerced into a data frame
train_math <- scaled[index_train_math,]
test_math <- scaled[-index_train_math,]
n_math <- names(train_math)
f_math <- as.formula(paste("Math_G3 ~ traveltime + studytime + failure + famrel + goout + Dalc + Walc + health + absences + Math_G1 + Math_G2", paste(n_math[!n_math %in% "Math_G3"], collapse = " + ")))
nn <- neuralnet(f_math,data=train_math,hidden=c(5,3),linear.output=T)
```

Below is a preview of my dataset:
[image]

May I know what is wrong with my code and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Your last line of code does not contain variable names introduced above. `f` and `train_` were not defined by the code above.

Comment: thank you i have corrected the names

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.  No one wants to type it in.  Instead, use `dput(head(dat_math, 20))` to make a text version of your data that we can cut and paste into R.